# That something be vs that something is

Tags: grammar, british-english

Which one of the following sentences is grammatically correct?

"That every A be B is clear"

"That every A is B is clear"

Also, is there a difference in meaning?

Comment: The first version might be grammatical, but it seems like an archaic or very formal usage.

Comment: The first would be a plausible usage in some areas of Mathematics. Depending on the referents of A an B, either might be more natural in s given context, but the version using "is" seems more likely in eh absence of context..

Comment: The syntax is a bit inverted. The intent is: "It is clear that A is B." In this order, it is even more obvious that "A be B" is incorrect—unless you're a pirate, in which case it "be" clear.

Comment: "Let every A be an element of the set *R*"